# How to burn 801MB iso file

Tags: xubuntu, iso, cd

I have ubuntu 11.10 (XFce) and I download Xubuntu 13.04 64Bit iso file that have 801MB and both brasero and XFburn can't burn that image on 800MB CD-R. Can I burn that image on that CD using overburn (those programs don't have that option, I use to do that on Windows but never on GNU/Linux) or do I need to buy larger CD?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably won't find a CD that will (naturally) support that size file, and overburning isn't recommended due to issues.

I'd recommend using a DVD instead, or if that's not an option, a USB drive.

EDIT: I'd emphasize trying to get a DVD... I personally had many issues with using my 8 GB USB drive.  The first time I attempted a DVD install was fully successful.

Comment: "isn't recommended due to... issues"? Can you elaborate? What is the danger of overburning, isn't there always some margin on a CD?

Comment: I'd recommend a USB. Easier to work with. Use LiLo if you need

Comment: Some optical drives do not support reading (or, alternatively, writing) past the intended disc max size.  Most of these are legacy, but it's always better to stay within the constraints of what we "know" as good practice, in my experience.  Otherwise, you're relying entirely on the end-user to be at the mercy of becoming SQA/Tester type mentalities.

Comment: use usb and LiLo or universal usb installer the best option according to me.

Comment: Using a USB is much easier than it used to be.  Most Ubuntu live CD images are hybrid mode nowadays so you can just use a raw image writer to write the exact same image to the USB.

Answer (score 8):

Besides a DVD, you have several other options.

1. Super Grub2 disk. Burn the [beta5](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/2013/05/06/super-grub2-disk-2-00-beta-5-released/) (or probably any later version) to a CD, and then put the ISO on a flash drive or something in a directory called `/boot-isos/`. Boot SG2D and select **detect loop bootable isos**. (Note that SG2D only searches drives for loop bootable ISOs that were detected when SG2D was booted, you don't seem to be able to detect a drive afterwards.)
2. Ubuntu ISOs are "hybrid" ISOs, which means you can [copy them to a flash drive using `dd`](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-11-10-Will-Be-Distributed-As-Hybrid-CD-USB-images-206765.shtml) and directly boot off of that. Also, SG2D above is also a Hybrid ISO
3. [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and various other tools will copy a ISO file into a flash drive and make it bootable, if you are reluctant to use `dd` (common nickname is "destroy data" because the syntax is a little weird and mistakes can be tough to recover from.)
4. U3 smart Flashdrives let you load the ISO file after creating a partition. It will then emulate a CD-ROM, even one with more space than 700 MB providing you set it up with enough space. Unfortunately, they stopped selling these back in 2009. This is a fantastic option for ISO files that are problematic to load, "loop boot", or "chainload" via Grub2. I use [`u3-tool`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/u3-tool/) to remove the inital software and replace it with my choice. You can get this via `apt-get` from the Ubuntu repositories.
5. [isostick](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/elegantinvention/isostick-the-optical-drive-in-a-usb-stick) seems like a more expensive way to get modern hardware that does the same thing as buying a vintage U3 flash drive off of ebay

Comment: 11 years later, add [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_start.html) to the top of the list. The program is easy to use and you can carry around and boot all kinds of ISOs. Flash drives are also much faster than CD or DVD drives.

Answer (score 2):

**k3b-2.8.2** allowed me to do a (relatively small and non-configurable) overburn, while xfburn wasn't allowing it (reporting low space)

Comment: Why this my theoretically answer the question, this question already has an answer, so it might have place in a comment.

Comment: @Wilf, this question is already full of people, who didn't even once overburn'd on Windows, there were no applications confirmed for the task, recommended answer is about getting DVD/flash memory (and possibly wasting the CD, isn't ecological way..).

Comment: I will support you on the use of K3B - just this answer came up in the [low quality review queue](http://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts). If you add more info about K3B, the steps you took, [a link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k3b/) or something, it may make this a better answer. Also stuff about checking the CD like you said ;)

Answer (score 1):

Of late, I've found dd to be the most reliable way of copying an ISO to a flash drive, and I think that's what you're going to end up doing because they are cheap, common, and large enough. unetbootin has not worked reliably for me the last several times I've used it.

Use

```
if=filename.iso of=/dev/usbdevice
```

with *filename*  and *usbdevice* replaced by the correct values for your system, and you're good to go.

**When using dd, always be careful that the input file and the output file are what you want them to be! You can overwrite the contents of your hard drive if you're not careful!!!**

Answer (score -2):

You can't burn it to a single layer DVD or split it. What you can do is mount it with something like Daemon Tools and then rip that your hard disk. Once it's in your hard drive and no longer in ISO format you can either shrink it to single layer size with something like DVDShrink or you can possibly split it with something like IFOEdit if you know what you are doing. I would recommend using DVDShrink as it can get complicated to split with IFOEdit if you are not very experienced in doing this.

Comment: These are all windows tools, and jcubic is on ubuntu 11.10.