# How to burn cd from live cd?

Tags: xubuntu, livedvd

I did this once, but I can't find instructions how to do that again. It was probably kernel option that make live cd save in ram.

I have old Xubuntu but want to install nested version of Xubuntu, I've downloaded the iso on my old laptop but it have broken DVD, so how can I run live CD, of old Xubuntu, put it in RAM so I can put empty DVD and then burn new Xubuntu?

Comment: This is kind of off topic and you have all the answers you need in your old question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/295407/how-to-burn-801mb-iso-file

Comment: @MichaelBay this is completly different question, I don't want to burn larger CD 801MB on CD but burn it when live CD is booted, where you can't remove CD/DVD from drive.

Comment: ⁺¹, it's a useful question. I remember having alike problem with the only working CD-ROM in old notebook without HDD, so I had to boot from a live-cd, and to burn using the same CD-ROM where I booted from. I had to make a lot of tricks to do it; don't remember the details though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the ubuntu wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM

Basically you need to edit kernel options from your liveCD while it's booting. While grub2 is loading, you should be able to use <kbd>e</kbd> and add option to the kernel `toram`.